# Loading Classes From the Client of a Remote EJB

Tags: ejb, rmi, ejb-3.1, ejb-3.2

I am trying to develop a standalone client for a remote enterprise bean that is deployed on an Oracle cloud that uses the WebLogic application container. The EJB method expects parameters of a specific interface called "Task". The EJB class looks something like this:

```
@Stateless
public class EJBClass implements RemoteEJB { 
 @Override
 public Object performTask(Task task){
    return task.doWork();
 }
}
```

The client application has customized implementations of the interface as follows:

```
class CustomTask implements Task{
  @Override
  public Object doWork(){/* perform customized work and return the result */}
}
```

And then there is a client class that invokes the EJB passing an instance of the CustomTask, as follows:

```
class Client{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Context ctx = getInitialContext();
    RemoteEJB ejb = (RemoteEJB) ctx.lookup(...);
    Object result = ejb.performTask(new CustomClass());
  }
}
```

I know that this is possible by providing the rmi codebase in Java RMI, but I cannot find any documentation on how to do this with EJBs. I am wondering if such a feature is available in EJBS (which is expected to be), and if yes, could someone please put me in the right direction as how to do this? I am searching on internet, but so far I haven't been able to find a proper tutorial or documentation. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you clarify, what is your question ?

Comment: @EmmanuelCollin, I am wondering if the traditional way of specifying rmi.server.codebase also works for a standalone client of an EJB! Thanks

Comment: The official Weblogic server java client page has your answer.
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs51/classdocs/API_client.html